# What is "Katamari Drive" mode?

Tags: touch-my-katamari

The Mode Shop has unlockable "Eternal" and "Katamari Drive" modes for the every level. I know that Eternal mode means the time limit is removed, but what is Katamari Drive mode? From what I read online, speed is increased, but by how much? What happens to "dash"? Is the time limit affected? How does the mode compare to the Drive level in *Katamari Forever*?

[image: Katamari Drive]

Answer (score 1):

Katamari Drive Is Basicly The Racetrack stage From We Love Katamari but anywhere you want.
The katamari will go by itself pretty fast,the time is shorter and you have to turn normally (no quickturn) and no dash (why faster are you Sonic?) Its sometimes its kinda hard but its required to 100% so good luck if you are going to do them :D